# forgot password using lightning component in community

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-community

want forgot password feature with lightning component  in community
i have seen many reference in visual force page but not able to  find it in lightning, so how can i achieve it in lightning  component

VisualForce:

Apex:

```
    public class TestForgotController { 


    public String username {get; set;} 

    public PageReference forgotPassword() { 

    if(username != '') {  
         User UserToReset = [Select Id, Username from User where Username = :Username and IsActive = true LIMIT 1];  
         boolean success = Site.forgotPassword(username);  
         PageReference pr = Page.CommunityForgotPasswordConfirm;     
         pr.setRedirect(true);  
         return pr;  
    }  
    return null; 

    }  
}
```

want same thing achieve in lightning component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have implemented this using below code and it is working on prod org as well.

```
     @AuraEnabled
  public static String forgotPassowrd(String userid) {
    String procesMsg = '';
    User user = [SELECT Id,Username FROM User WHERE Id = :userid]; //Added username in query for test class
    if (user != null) {
      if (Site.isValidUsername(user.Username)) {
        Site.forgotPassword(user.Username);
        procesMsg = 'LoginResetSuccess';
      } else {
        procesMsg = 'LoginResetWarning';
      }
    }
    return procesMsg;
  }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply but i don't know why i email is not going, can you tell me what can  be wrong

Comment: Check in Setup > Logs > Email Log Files . You can also check https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199303&type=1

Comment: after your comment i checked it at the same place but there are not any email logs  there can you tell what can be wrong

Comment: Try this https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005166&type=1

Comment: thanks it is working completely fine now, actually the community was not active it was in preview mode but after making community active it is working absolutely fine

Comment: code is working but there is couple of bugs in above code. 1. need to handle `List has no rows for assignment to SObject`  exception 2. using userName field without querying `Username` in soql query